# Spring activated profile is being ignored - without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I am using spring to run my app. Here is my configuration.yaml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    default: default
db:
  host: mysql:3306
  schema: my_db
  user: user
  password: pass

---

spring:
  profiles: dev
db:
  host: localhost:3306

---

spring:
  profiles: prod
db:
  host: mysql:3306
```

When running the service via intellij I am both tried to set the VM options (`-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`) and environment variable to `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev`.
Both didn't work. It seems like it takes the last profile, in my example it takes the prod profile.

The configuration is loaded via an xml:

```
  <bean id="yamlProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:config.yaml"/>
  </bean>

  <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="yamlProperties"/>
```

Here is how I boot my app:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val context = ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/api-applicationContext-all.xml")
  val router = context.getBean("router") as Router
  router.start()
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try to rename the file to `application.yml` - it's the default name recognised with Spring-Boot.

Comment: I seems like spring reads it, its just it is not being following the flags

Comment: @Nikolas, it didn't help

Comment: @vlio20 where else is the `prod` profile defined or set other than the `application.yml`?

Comment: try this `--spring.profiles.active=dev` or `spring.profiles.active=dev` this should work

Comment: @Deadpool, I also tried VM options `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` and application parameters: `--spring.profiles.active=dev`

Comment: did you try without `--` it worked for me

Comment: @Deadpool, here is my config: http://prntscr.com/kezuyk

Comment: sorry keep it in program arguments not in vm arguments and remove it from vm arguments

Comment: removed from vm... didn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177452/discussion-between-deadpool-and-vlio20).

Comment: application.properties will always win over yaml. Make sure that this is not the case

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich no such

Comment: I'm using `@ActiveProfiles({"test", "accesstokenretrievalfailure"})` in a test and no matter what is the profiles order `test` always win :(. Using `@ActiveProfiles({"accesstokenretrievalfailure"})` works as expected. Using `@ActiveProfiles({"xaccesstokenretrievalfailure", "test"})` the order is `test` then `xaccesstokenretrievalfailure` : ) ) ) check the **x**